# How to send "LE extended create Connection" in BLE with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4

I'm using Minew S1 Humidity and Temperature sensor in my project, I'm trying to connect to Raspberry Pi with this sensor using gatttool and bluetoothctl, but the problem in both tools is the connection does not persist for long it just disconnects automatically within 10 seconds, so to check the problem I used my mobile and tried to connect with BeaconSet+ app, which connected successfully as expected, and tried to compare bluetooth packets of Raspberry Pi and android mobile, the difference I found is packets from mobile initiates connection by sending "[LE Extended Create Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Dgw9.png)" and from the Raspberry Pi to initiate connection it sends "[LE Create Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLnYD.png)".

Bluetooth Debug data :

```
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                              #37 [hci0] 23.110065
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) plen 25                                                                #38 [hci0] 23.110095
        Scan interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Scan window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Filter policy: White list is not used (0x00)
        Peer address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address: AC:23:3F:AB:7B:D8 (Shenzhen Minew Technologies Co., Ltd.)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Min connection interval: 30.00 msec (0x0018)
        Max connection interval: 50.00 msec (0x0028)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
        Min connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
        Max connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                #39 [hci0] 23.110613
      LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19                                                                                #40 [hci0] 23.210757
      LE Connection Complete (0x01)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Role: Master (0x00)
        Peer address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address: AC:23:3F:AB:7B:D8 (Shenzhen Minew Technologies Co., Ltd.)
        Connection interval: 48.75 msec (0x0027)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
        Master clock accuracy: 0x00
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 37                                                                     {0x0001} [hci0] 23.210785
        LE Address: AC:23:3F:AB:7B:D8 (Shenzhen Minew Technologies Co., Ltd.)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 24
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (complete): 1 entry
          Unknown (0xffe1)
        Service Data (UUID 0xffe1): a101641cfd48e6d87bab3f23ac
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) plen 2                                                         #41 [hci0] 23.210905
        Handle: 64
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                #42 [hci0] 23.211771
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 14                                                                             #43 [hci0] 23.211775
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                    ..........      
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                                                                                #44 [hci0] 23.337233
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Features: 0x21 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
          LE Data Packet Length Extension
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                                                               #45 [hci0] 23.337677
      ATT: Exchange MTU Request (0x02) len 2
        Client RX MTU: 517
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                                                               #46 [hci0] 23.532018
      ATT: Exchange MTU Response (0x03) len 2
        Server RX MTU: 23
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                                                               #47 [hci0] 23.532452
      ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2
        Handle: 0x0003
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                   #48 [hci0] 23.580957
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 10                                                                              #49 [hci0] 23.629552
      ATT: Read Response (0x0b) len 5
        Value: 6e52463578
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                                                               #50 [hci0] 23.629713
      ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2
        Handle: 0x0005
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                                                               #51 [hci0] 23.727010
      ATT: Read Response (0x0b) len 2
        Value: 0000
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                                                               #52 [hci0] 23.727179
      ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2
        Handle: 0x0027
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                   #53 [hci0] 23.775948
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2


> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                                                                           #54 [hci0] 32.502249
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                                                                   {0x0001} [hci0] 32.502320
        LE Address: AC:23:3F:AB:7B:D8 (Shenzhen Minew Technologies Co., Ltd.)
        Reason: Connection terminated by remote host (0x03)
```

Thank you

Comment: Nope, it simply tells you that your mobile and your Raspi use different Bluetooth software.

Comment: @Risto So what is the way to communicate with sensor using Raspberry Pi, as mobile communicates with sensor

Comment: If I had to debug such an error, I would ask myself why the connection is disconnected. I would first look at the disconnect reason and then look for a possible solution for that.

Comment: @Risto I added my debug data in post, I could not found perfect reason for it, and one more, in same android mobile I'm able to connect it using BeaconSet+ app but unable to connect using nRF connect app, nRF connect app behaves same as Raspberry Pi.

Comment: You could post the log from the mobile as well. The extended hci command is just an extended hci command to allow more featurers in the protocol between the host and the controller. The actual over-the-air packets will look the same, assuming the normal 1M PHY is used for advertising.

Comment: @LavudijanniSubhash everything looks perfect
`Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)` As you can see your sensor terminated the connection. As it is battery operated and maintaining the connection costs a lot of energy and drains it, the connection is terminated after a certain time without data traffic. So if you don't want the connection to be terminated, you have to exchange data with the sensor. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Risto I noticed it, as you said to keep connection, I continuously tried to exchange data with sensor, the time also the connection is disconnected but this time time the Reason is different `Reason: Connection timeout (0x08)`